# if/else | Changing html in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$("#button_announcement").click(function(){ 
    $('#button_announcement').html('Hide') ? $(this).html('Show') : $(this).html('Hide');
});
```

I have a button on my page which show/hide my announcement. I wanted to change button html after clicking it but this code change just once from 'hide' to 'show' it don't want to change from show to hide... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.html('Hide')` will *always* set the HTML to `Hide`. It won't retrieve the HTML

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$('#button_announcement').html('Hide') ? ...
```

to this:

```
$('#button_announcement').html() === 'Hide' ? ...
```

The former just assigns 'Hide' as the HTML always, but the latter checks if the HTML of `#button_announcement` is 'Hide'.

Comment: It works when i change just condition. `$('#button_announcement').html() === 'Hide'` Should I change the rest of the code similar to this? And another question. Why did you use three characters equals? Im new in jquery and as i remember in JS i never used '==='.

Comment: @szpanel -- 1) Yes, you will have to use such code at every place where you want such work. Please look at Rory's answer as well because it is quite efficient. 2) Have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're using the setter of `html()` in the condition. You need to use the getter and check the value instead. Note that using the `text()` method here would be better practice:

```js
$("#button_announcement").click(function(){ 
    $(this).text() == 'Hide' ? $(this).text('Show') : $(this).text('Hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button_announcement">Hide</button>
```

Alternatively you can provide a function to `text()` which updates the value based on its current setting. This avoids the need for the explicit getter:

```js
$("#button_announcement").click(function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, t) {
    return t == 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button_announcement">Hide</button>
```

Comment: `$("#button_announcement").click(function(){ 
    $('#button_announcement').text() == 'Hide' ? $(this).text('Show') : 
    $(this).text('Hide');
    });`

`$("#button_announcement").click(function(){
  $('#button_announcement').html() === 'Hide' ? $(this).html('Show') : $(this).html('Hide');
 });`

Thank you. Just ask, both are correct?

Comment: Yes, although I would use the `this` reference within the event handler to save a DOM access.